# Adjust command line options upon restart

Tags: java, eclipse, restart

We're building an application in Java based on Eclipse. Its entry point implements `IApplication`. In some cases, we let Eclipse restart the application by returning the exit code `IApplication.EXIT_RESTART`.

The command line options on restart are the same as those given on the console. Is there a way to adjust/extend them for subsequent invocations?

`org.eclipse.equinox.launcher 1.3.100v20150511-1540`

Comment: `org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.actions.OpenWorkspaceAction` does this to switch to a different workspace. But the APIs it uses are all **internal** so should not be used.

Comment: Greg, who doesn't want to play with scissors and matches? Could you point me to some code example that demonstrates this capability?

Comment: I don't know of anything else that uses this. You will have to read the Eclipse source. Since this is an internal API it may be different on different releases of Eclipse.